# Yosemite to AFP Ubuntu server connection freezes (UBUNTU CNID dbase error)

Tags: macos, network, unix, afp

I have problems with Yosemite network connections to ubuntu server.
Connection working for a while and freez after one minute or little more.
This is big 3 TB server for work, with lot of files like photos and indesign files. I'm off spootlight and icon

```
    30.08.2015 20:19:42,399 KernelEventAgent[106]: tid 54485244 found 1 filesystem(s) with problem(s)
    30.08.2015 20:19:42,000 kernel[0]: ASP_TCP Disconnect: triggering reconnect by bumping reconnTrigger from curr value 35 on so 0xffffff8031a957b0
    30.08.2015 20:19:43,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  doing reconnect on /Volumes/polaftp
    30.08.2015 20:19:43,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  posting to KEA EINPROGRESS for /Volumes/polaftp
    30.08.2015 20:19:43,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Max reconnect time: 30 secs, Connect timeout: 15 secs for /Volumes/polaftp
    30.08.2015 20:19:43,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  connect to the server /Volumes/polaftp
    30.08.2015 20:19:43,400 KernelEventAgent[106]: tid 54485244 received event(s) VQ_NOTRESP (1)
    30.08.2015 20:19:43,401 KernelEventAgent[106]: tid 54485244 found 1 filesystem(s) with problem(s)
    30.08.2015 20:19:43,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Logging in with uam 8 /Volumes/polaftp
    30.08.2015 20:19:43,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Restoring session /Volumes/polaftp
    30.08.2015 20:19:48,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Primary Reconnect failed 22 on /Volumes/polaftp
    30.08.2015 20:19:48,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  trying Secondary Reconnect on /Volumes/polaftp


31.08.2015 13:31:05,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Max reconnect time: 30 secs, Connect timeout: 15 secs for /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:05,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  connect to the server /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:05,618 KernelEventAgent[106]: tid 54485244 received event(s) VQ_NOTRESP (1)
31.08.2015 13:31:05,618 KernelEventAgent[106]: tid 54485244 found 1 filesystem(s) with problem(s)
31.08.2015 13:31:05,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Logging in with uam 8 /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:05,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Restoring session /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Primary Reconnect failed 22 on /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  trying Secondary Reconnect on /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:10,687 KernelEventAgent[106]: tid 54485244 received event(s) VQ_NOTRESP (1)
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: ASP_TCP CancelOneRequest: cancelling slot 31 error 35 reqID 23375 flags 0x29 afpCmd 0x44 so 0xffffff801b5933d8
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: ASP_TCP CancelOneRequest: cancelling slot 32 error 35 reqID 23376 flags 0x29 afpCmd 0x11 so 0xffffff801b5933d8
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: ASP_TCP CancelOneRequest: cancelling slot 33 error 35 reqID 23377 flags 0x29 afpCmd 0x45 so 0xffffff801b5933d8
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: ASP_TCP CancelOneRequest: cancelling slot 34 error 35 reqID 23378 flags 0x29 afpCmd 0x11 so 0xffffff801b5933d8
31.08.2015 13:31:10,687 KernelEventAgent[106]: tid 54485244 found 1 filesystem(s) with problem(s)
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: ASP_TCP CancelOneRequest: cancelling slot 35 error 35 reqID 23379 flags 0x29 afpCmd 0x11 so 0xffffff801b5933d8
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  get the reconnect token
31.08.2015 13:31:10,000 kernel[0]: ASP_TCP Disconnect: triggering reconnect by bumping reconnTrigger from curr value 94 on so 0xffffff801b5933d8
31.08.2015 13:31:11,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  doing reconnect on /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:11,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  posting to KEA EINPROGRESS for /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:11,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Max reconnect time: 30 secs, Connect timeout: 15 secs for /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:11,000 kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  connect to the server /Volumes/polaftp
31.08.2015 13:31:11,689 KernelEventAgent[106]: tid 54485244 received event(s) VQ_NOTRESP (1)
```

Worst is the SMB2 protocol not working better at all 
I have files locking problem, vanishing files and many others :(

please help! :)

Mac Pro, OS X Yosemite (10.10.5), null

EDIT:
ok,this is serious base erron on Ubuntu server:

```
Aug 31 22:39:00.846256 netatalk[12444] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:01.846180 netatalk[12459] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:02.846045 netatalk[12460] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:03.846805 netatalk[12461] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:04.846563 netatalk[12462] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:05.846312 netatalk[12463] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:06.846127 netatalk[12464] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:07.846877 netatalk[12465] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:08.846615 netatalk[12466] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:09.846375 netatalk[12469] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:10.846220 netatalk[12470] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:11.847036 netatalk[12471] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:12.846831 netatalk[12472] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:13.846600 netatalk[12473] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:14.846377 netatalk[12474] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:15.846140 netatalk[12475] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:16.846887 netatalk[12476] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:17.846645 netatalk[12477] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:18.846421 netatalk[12480] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:19.846283 netatalk[12482] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:20.846122 netatalk[12485] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:21.846842 netatalk[12486] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:22.846569 netatalk[12487] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:23.846305 netatalk[12488] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:24.846089 netatalk[12489] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:25.846833 netatalk[12492] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:26.846596 netatalk[12493] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:27.846366 netatalk[12494] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 31 22:39:28.846195 netatalk[12495] {netatalk.c:332} (error:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
```

i'm try to recreate base, but i have error:

```
dbd -f /home/poladesign/FTP/
Aug 31 20:47:52.943722 dbd[5714] {cnid_dbd.c:152} (error:CNID): getfd: getsockopt says: Connection refused
Aug 31 20:47:52.943853 dbd[5714] {cnid_dbd.c:176} (error:CNID): tsock_getfd: no suitable network config from CNID server (localhost:4700): Connection refused
Aug 31 20:47:52.943882 dbd[5714] {cnid_dbd.c:407} (error:CNID): transmit: connection refused (volume polaftp)
Failed to wipe CNID db
```

Comment: Great detail. Could you explain a bit how you establish the filesystem mount? Have you tried using a tool like transmit to rule out the OS and see if it's networking or finder related?

Comment: i'm mounting using finder ctrl+K. I'm also try mounting using terminal, but i get error message:
sudo mount_afp afp://192.168.101.254/polaftp/ /Volumes/test
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error -5002, errno is -5002
i don't see any possiblity to connect by transmit to afp server. Only ftp. ssh etc.

Comment: I'm try making connections by Disk Order manager. After copy some files i have the some freezes...

Comment: @WhiteMAX666 Please add the versions of Ubuntu and netatalk to your question